# Return touple by mapping two signals - ReactiveKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapping, reactive-programming, reactivekit

I have two distinct signals:

`Signal<A, Error>`

`Signal<B, Error>`

I am trying to map them together to return a signal containing touple of both types as such, using ReactiveKit:
`Signal<(A, B), Error>`

I have tried `map()`, `flatMapLatest()`, `handleEvents()` but to no avail. I am sure there is a way how to achieve this I just cannot seem to find it. Please note that I am not trying to observe the signal, just map it together so that I can produce a touple of the two types.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this is what you need:

```
public func combineLatest  
    <A: SignalProtocol, B: SignalProtocol>  
    (_ a: A, _ : B) -> Signal<(A.Element, B.Element), A.Error>  
    where A.Error == B.Error
```

I.e.

```
sigAB = Signal.combineLatest(sigA, sigB)
```

[More functions here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ReactiveKit/3.0.0/Functions.html#/s:F11ReactiveKit13combineLatestu1_RxS_14SignalProtocol_S0_0_S0_wx5Errorzw0_S1_w_S1_zw0_S1_rFTxq_q0__GVS_6SignalTwx7Elementw_S3_w0_S3__wxS1__)